# Rules: use a View's result as a condition?

Tags: views, rules

How can I use the results of a view as a condition in a rule?

I have rule that fires off a *daily digest* email with contents from a view (using [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules)). The view simply returns nodes that have a specific field value. When the view doesn't return any nodes, the rule still fires off what is essentially an empty email. I want to prevent this. I need a condition like "View has no results" (negated)… but I don't see anything like that. What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Even though your own answer is indeed a way to solve your question, it doesn't say that for this to work, it requires the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to be enabled (without that, you cannot add a Rules Condition as an extra rules Action).

An alternative solution to solve your question, is to use the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to transform your view into a VBO view, so that you can use a Rules Condition "***Check number of results returned by a VBO View***" in which you can perfectly construct the Rules Condition you're looking for.

Have a look at "[this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/180159/39516)" for an illustration of how this specific Rules Condition is used.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to pull this off by adding a condition to the *Actions* section, as opposed to the (more logical) *Conditions* section. Here's what I did:

1. Added a *conditional* to the Actions section
2. Added an *if* to the conditional
3. Added the *Data value is empty* condition and negated it
4. The *Data to check* is one of the fields from my view, in my case `[created:0]`
5. Added the action (in my case, *Send mail to all users of a role*) and nested it under this new condition

While this does seem to work, it feels like more of a workaround than a solution. But, hey, if it works, it works. Anyway, I'm open to more direct approaches if they're out there.