# how to use token in "Execute custom PHP code" in a rule

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I used "**Execute custom PHP code**" in my pricing rule.

However I got Notice when I checkout:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant testsku - assumed 'testsku' in eval() (line 7 of /var/www/jmu/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code).
>   Notice: Undefined variable: line_item in eval() (line 7 of /var/www/jmu/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code).

I know there must be something wrong with my token replace code:

```
$line_item_label = token_replace([commerce-line-item:line-item-label],array('commerce_line_item' =>$line_item));
```

I used "line-item-label" as product sku's machine name

Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Where and how did you use `$line_item_label`? It seems to me that this variable has the value *testsku* and that you misused it as a constant somewhere else. Your error also demonstrates that you should avoid using PHP code in a Rule. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/108447/16550 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very beginning, I just saw "$commerce_line_item" can be used in php code, but I wanted to use `[commerce-line-item:line-item-label]` value which showed in the token place. So I tried to use token_replace to get this value.

Finally, I figure out how to get that value and use it in PHP Code.
[image]
Although it isn't showed in the variable name place, we can still use `$commerce_line_item -> line_item_label` in the PHP Code. This works for me.